# How to hdfs shell script handle --config option

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

When I run `${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}/bin/hdfs --config ${HADOOP_CONF_DIR} dfs -ls /`, How does hdfs shell script handle --config option?

The script does not compare `"COMMAND" = "--config"`, though COMMAND is `COMMAND=$1`

[hdfs shell script is here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.2-RC2/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/hdfs)

[COMMAND=$1](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.2-RC2/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/hdfs#L81)

Comment: Have you seen this first lines in `hdfs` script: `. $HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR/hdfs-config.sh`?

Comment: Yes, I saw that [file][1].But There is not handling --config.

[1]: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.2-RC2/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/hdfs-config.sh

Comment: Because it is found in the `hadoop-config.sh`script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option `--config` is handled in the `hadoop-config.sh` script, invoked by the `hdfs-config.sh` script, which is invoked in turn by `hdfs`:

```
#check to see if the conf dir is given as an optional argument
if [ $# -gt 1 ]
then
    if [ "--config" = "$1" ]
          then
              shift
              confdir=$1
              if [ ! -d "$confdir" ]; then
                echo "Error: Cannot find configuration directory: $confdir"
                exit 1
             fi
              shift
              HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$confdir
    fi
fi
```

You only had to dig into the script chain.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for your answer. It is really helpful for me.
I lose my concentration, While I dig the scripts.